# Set variable in SQL equal to database name

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I want to execute a `.sql` file by `.bat` file (where db=input name in cmd)

The top of the `.sql` file looks like this:

```
USE $(db)

DECLARE @Database varchar(500)
SET @Database = $(db)
```

But after executing the `.bat` file, an error occurs at line 4 of the `.sql` file
Apparently, `variable = $(db)` does not work.

Is there another way in order to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLCMD variables, so change your batch file to call SQLCMD rather than ISQL

```
@echo off
sqlcmd -E -S myserver -i sample.sql -v db=YourDBName
```

sample.sql content would be like this

```
USE $(db)

DECLARE @Database varchar(500)
SET @Database = $(db)
```